# Can't implements Scrollview in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, uiscrollview, android-xml

why I can not show the scroll view in my project, when run does not look scrollview in my project, do I put scrollview not quite right? How Scrollview placement should be, so that all items that are in my project can get scrollview This my XML Code [image: scrollview]

### activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".BoxOfficeDetailActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPosterImage"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/large_movie_poster" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCriticsScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPosterImage"
        android:text="@string/critics_score"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvAudienceScore"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvAudienceScore"
        android:text="@string/cast"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivPosterImage"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPosterImage"
        android:text="@string/movie_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivPosterImage"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAudienceScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvCriticsScore"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvCriticsScore"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/audi_score"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSynopsis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvCriticsConsensus"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:text="@string/synopsis" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCriticsConsensus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:text="@string/cosensus"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your scrollview contains nothing so thats why you wont see it

Comment: so how I am supposed to be? @tyczj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scrollview height should not be defined in wrap because you want it to scroll.
Also the linear inside the scroll should be in wrap for its height and have some elements inside.

Suggestion if you don't mind using linears :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context=".BoxOfficeDetailActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivPosterImage"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxHeight="300dp"
                android:src="@drawable/large_movie_poster" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivPosterImage"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPosterImage"
                    android:text="@string/movie_title"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCriticsScore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvTitle"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPosterImage"
                    android:text="@string/critics_score"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAudienceScore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvCriticsScore"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvCriticsScore"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/audi_score"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCast"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvAudienceScore"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvAudienceScore"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/cast"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCriticsConsensus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cosensus"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSynopsis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvCriticsConsensus"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:text="@string/synopsis"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where I should put the scrollview? help me to edit the code @xavier

Comment: Do you want the whole page scrolling or just the part in the bottom (below the image) ?

Comment: I want all pages scrolling, so how its code of scrollview? @Xavier

Comment: I edited my answer with a suggestion for your layout. Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        tools:context=".BoxOfficeDetailActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1">

       <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivPosterImage"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="300dp"
            android:src="@drawable/large_movie_poster" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCriticsScore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPosterImage"
            android:text="@string/critics_score"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCast"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvAudienceScore"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvAudienceScore"
            android:text="@string/cast"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivPosterImage"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivPosterImage"
            android:text="@string/movie_title"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAudienceScore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvCriticsScore"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvCriticsScore"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/audi_score"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSynopsis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvCriticsConsensus"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:text="@string/synopsis" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCriticsConsensus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cosensus"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i have issue, if i use your code, like this @+id/ivPosterImage is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout and Invalid layout param in a LinearLayout, why?

Comment: if you want it to scroll you have to play inside the scroll view,but scroll view can have only one direct parent so to make your code work replace linear layout with relative edited in answer

Comment: The issue resurfaced as android: layout_alignLeft = "@ + id / scrollView1", but after the TextView I Clean up your incorrect, scrollview still can't @suhail

Comment: what scroll view still can't

Comment: still does not work, it looks to be a mess @Suhail, cek my edit post